# How to know if home screen currently running at the foreground

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-service, android-task

I am making a parental control app.
The user can run other program from my app.
When they hit the home button and goes to the home screen, I want my app to detect it so that it can be redirected to my app.
How can I do this?

Comment: You don't do this.  You would create a replacement Launcher.

Comment: So there is no other way? Btw, thank you bro

Comment: Yes.  Gimme a few minutes and I'll post you an example of what I mean.